# How can I implement a fallback function when some function is missing(at compile time)?

Tags: c++, glibc

My goal is:

1. if `pthread_setname_np` is defined in glibc, we will use glibc's version.
2. otherwise, we will use a fallback function `pthread_setname_np` which actually do nothing to prevent compile errors.

This need to be done at compile time.

So I write the following codes

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <pthread.h>

__attribute__((weak)) int pthread_setname_np(pthread_t thread, const char *name) { printf("foo\n"); return 0; }

int main() {
    pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "bar");
}
```

IMO, if I run `g++ test_free_bsd.cpp -o test_free_bsd -lpthread`, since the symbol is already defined in `pthread`, so the compile will not link my self-defined symbol.

However, the program still prints out "foo", which means it actually uses my weak symbol.

Then it occurred to me that my self-defined `pthread_setname_np` is in the same unit with `main`, there are no linking. So I changed to the following

```
// g++ test_free_bsd.cpp test_free_bsd2.cpp -o test_free_bsd -lpthread
// test_free_bsd.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <pthread.h>

int main() {
    pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "bar");
}

// test_free_bsd2.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <pthread.h>
__attribute__((weak)) int pthread_setname_np(pthread_t thread, const char *name) { printf("foo\n"); return 0; }
```

However, the program still prints out `foo`. So I am lost here. IMO, in test_free_bsd.cpp, it will link `pthread_setname_np` in glibc, rather than in test_free_bsd2.cpp which is a weak symbol.

=== UPDATE ===

Why I wan to do this? There is a fallback in codes of [Clickhouse](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/6aefd1bc91f8bb3109d2c2ffe984166df2dcbaf8/base/glibc-compatibility/glibc-compatibility.c#L140). I am using these codes in my project, though I don't know why they are here. However, I don't want to change its behavior. I only want these lines to take effects only we are sure the glibc we linked to do not has `pthread_setname_np`.

Comment: I want to do it at compile time.

Comment: Why do you assume that `pthread_setname_np` is not a defined as a weak symbol in the glibc?

Comment: It can be done at runtime if you make `pthread_setname_np` a weak symbol and check if it was linked: https://godbolt.org/z/KWzrsMWb1 but this should be doable at link time

Comment: @Artyer Well, is using weak symbol a sensible way here, or should I use some other way, e.g. some template magic?

Comment: `There is a fallback in codes of Clickhouse` That's not a fallback, that's an override. If glibc introduces `pthread_setname_np`, clickhouse will still use it's own version. `we are sure the glibc we linked to do not has pthread_setname_np` Then why don't you do it _like_ clickhouse then, with a configure option and optionally compiled _override_ of the functions? https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/3a027d285f8d2058211f1186ba4cc30d6562635f/CMakeLists.txt#L159 It's not a "fallback". It's an option.

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD `pthread_setname_np` seems to exists, it is defined in `pthread_setname_np.h`. I don't know why you get a linker error (I can't test it.)

However, you should be able to use `#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE` around your `pthread_setname_np` to only define it if it isn't defined by `pthread.h`.

Comment: In clickhouse, there is a fallback, https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/6aefd1bc91f8bb3109d2c2ffe984166df2dcbaf8/base/glibc-compatibility/glibc-compatibility.c#L140. I use these codes, though I don't know why it is here. However, I don't want to change its behavior. I only want these lines to take effects only we are sure the glibc we linked to do not has `pthread_setname_np`.